# Understanding で over に in Noun + 的 + で

Tags: particle-に, particle-で

In the song lyrics to "A Piece of Blue Glass Moon":
https://miraikyun.com/reona-seimeisen-lyrics-tsukihime-a-piece-of-blue-glass-moon-theme-song/

Nouns + 的で are used a lot.  I would of expected に or な after 的.  Can someone explain why に is not being used, or what nuance で has here?
文学的で　退廃的で
現実的で　空想的で

感情的で　感傷的で
快楽的で　壊滅的で

Answer (score 1):

> 文学的で 退廃的で
> 現実的で 空想的で
> 感情的で 感傷的で
> 快楽的で 壊滅的で
> 絶対的で 普遍的で
> 不自然な「今」の見方を

「文学的で」「退廃的で」「現実的で」 etc... are all 連用形 (continuative form) of 形容動詞 (na-adjective).

They continue to 不自然な今の見方を.

「文学的で退廃的で現実的で空想的で感情的で感傷的で快楽的で壊滅的で絶対的で普遍的で不自然な」 all modify the noun 「今」

Examples:

> きれいな + 静かな + 公園 → きれい**で**静かな公園 (a clean and quiet park)
> 独創的な + 画期的な + 商品 → 独創的**で**画期的な商品 (a creative and revolutionary product)